# Python: Understanding Memcached

Tags: python, memcached

I have a web application where a user enters the main page, uploads a text, submits it and a bunch of code starts running in the background and work on the text the user submitted.

Because this takes a long time i separated the hole process in 2 main methods. The first one saves the necesary data in a key/value pair in Memcached, and the second
one uses that data from the first method and keeps on working. NO databases

I am probably really wrong but,
The very first thing that i am afraid of is that beacuse i cannot save anything in a database, that if 2 anonymous (there is no user registration also) users enter at the same time in the page and upload something and then because of Memcached saving all the texts in memory, that this could mess up the texts and show something to the users that has nothing to do with the texts they uploaded

This fear comes from things i read like: `"For the first visitor to the website a query will be used to request information from a database. When that information is retrieved, it is also copied to the Memcached server. The next visitor to the site has the advantage of not having to wait for a database query"`

If i do this:

```
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'])

def saca(lines):
    lineas = []
    for line in lines:
        s = re.sub(r"[\d/():,+-<>?¿¡!]", "", line)
        lineas.append(s)
    palabras = []
    ...
    mc.set("key":"value")


def get_random():
    baria = mc.get("key")
```

It should work because is just me. But with a bunch of users well...

This is me not really understanding how memcached really works so that´s the reason of this simple question: Can memcached mess up things in this scenario where there are no databases and is all in the fly?. Should i save also the information i need for the second method in the Session?.

I hope this gets an answer, is very long.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Reason why i cannot pass the data from one method to the other is because when the first method ends the UI is updated, when this happens a new button appears on the screen. When the user clicks this new button there is when the second method stars running and it needs to use some of the first method's information.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what memcached is supposed to be doing in this scenario. How are the two functions called? Why can't you just pass the data from one to the other?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i edited my question.

Comment: `memcached` may not be a good option for you. Its a cache and will discard data randomly even if you want to keep it around for a user to consume. `memcached` is usually used when data can be shared by many users. You can game it by adding a unique user id to the keys. An anonymous user could get a unique guid sent as a cookie that you append to the keys.

Comment: @tdelaney could you point me in the right direction on how to add a unique user id to the keys and how to sent  it as a cookie? do not need a big explanation if you don´t want to, just where to look. Or add it as an answer and i will mark it. Thanks

Comment: Your web framework may already have all you need to identify anonymous users. If not, see about setting cookies and using `uuid.uuid4()` to generate the id. Whatever you currently use as a key, add the uuid such as `user_id = uuid.uuid4()` and `mykey = user_id + originalkey`.

Comment: @tdelaney ok, i will take a look at that. Thanks